# Extend a class from different puppet module

Tags: puppet

I need to extend a class from a different Puppet module. Is it possible to do this? If yes, what would be the syntax?

Comment: Although it is possible to do so, you almost surely *do not* need to extend a Puppet class, especially one from a different module.  The Puppet Language Specification is actually quite readable for a document of its kind; [it describes the syntax and presents an example](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_classes.html#inheritance).  It also remarks about the (very few) appropriate uses for this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Puppet, it is possible for a class a::b to inherit class a via the `inherits` keyword. This allows class a::b to "extend" class a.

**Note that Puppet recommends that you should rarely if ever need to do this. In particular, most of what can be achieved by inheritance can also be achieved by just including the base class by using the include function**. For more information, see the documentation [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_classes.html#inheritance).

If you do choose to use inheritance, class a is automatically declared first; class a becomes the parent scope of class a::b, so it receives copies of all variables and resource defaults; and the code in class a::b has permission to override resource attributes that are set in class a.

Using this pattern, it is also possible for class a::b to use a variable from class a as a default for one of its class parameters. This led to the "params pattern" where a params.pp file is used to set class defaults.

The following simple code example illustrates all of these features:

```
class a {
  File {
    mode => '0755',
  }
  file { '/tmp/foo':
    ensure => absent,
  }
  $x = 'I, Foo'
}

class a::b (
  $y = $a::x  # default from class a.
) inherits a {

  # Override /tmp/foo's ensure
  # and content attributes.

  File['/tmp/foo'] {
    ensure  => file,
    content => $y,
  }

  # Both /tmp/foo and /tmp/bar
  # will receive the default file
  # mode of 0755.

  file { '/tmp/bar':
    ensure => file,
  }
}
```

And using Rspec to express the catalog's expected end-state:

```
describe 'a::b' do
  it 'overrides ensure attribute' do
    is_expected.to contain_file('/tmp/foo').with({
      'ensure'  => 'file',
    })
  end
  it 'inherits content from $x' do
    is_expected.to contain_file('/tmp/foo').with({
      'content' => "I, Foo",
    })
  end
  it 'file defaults inherited' do
    is_expected.to contain_file('/tmp/foo').with({
      'mode' => '0755',
    })
    is_expected.to contain_file('/tmp/bar').with({
      'mode' => '0755',
    })
  end
end
```

Tests pass:

```
a::b
  overrides ensure attribute
  inherits content from $x
  file defaults inherited

Finished in 0.15328 seconds (files took 1.2 seconds to load)
3 examples, 0 failures
```

A note about "plusignment".

As also described in the documentation, it is possible, when overriding a resource attribute that is an array, to add to that array instead of replacing using the `+>` "plusignment" operator. It is a rarely used feature, but should be mentioned in this context. See the link above for a code example.

Comment: Good answer, but still worth noting that class inheritance has been discouraged by Puppet since the low 3.x, and `params` inheritance since the high 4.x.

Comment: Yes, I did say to pay attention to Puppet's recommendations about when to use, and when not to use, inheritance. I guess it's still a matter of opinion? There's actually an interesting use of inheritance in Craig Dunn's original roles & profiles article https://www.craigdunn.org/2012/05/239/

Comment: Yeah in May 2012 class inheritance would still have been considered ok.

Comment: Class inheritance was not generally considered ok in 2012 (around the time v3 was introduced), but there was perhaps more diversity of opinion then than there is now.  Within my Puppet experience (dating back to 0.24), there has never been a good reason to choose class inheritance when `include` would do.  That was in fact expressed explicitly in the Puppet docs at least as far back as [v2.7](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-docs/blob/master/source/puppet/2.7/lang_classes.markdown), though the docs of that time did not recognize the params class pattern (which is no exception!).

Comment: In light of this discussion, I have edited the answer to prominently warn the reader that Puppet does not recommend inheritance.